# holotoolkit failed to build

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm trying to build an app for hololens, impotring the holo toolkit, and make the build. this is the result:
[image]
any idea?

Comment: Did you switch the Plattform in the build setting to `Universal Windows Plattform`? Apparently you are trying to build it on iOS?

Comment: no... it's on uwp...

Comment: Just checking, you are using https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity ? Holotoolkit can also mean an old similar but unmaintained library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are install instructions for MRTK here https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/GettingStarted.md.  That is the best place to get started, make sure you use the version of unity specified (although it will officially support  2018.1.9f1 with the next major release, and most 2018 versions do currently work, the current supported version is still 2017)